# Upgrading an iPad app from 3.2 to 6.1 on Xcode

Tags: ipad

I am starting to work on iPad application which was created in 2011 for `iOS 3.2`. Now I would like to upgrade the application to be able to work properly on `iOS 6.1` and also add some new features. What are your advices to do these tasks? Main points that I capture so far as:

1. Add storyboard
2. Remove xibs
3. Fix .m/.h missing file errors

Do you know when I add the storyboard if it is going to be updated with my app screens automatically? Or do I have to introduce the screen all the properties one by one?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to add your screens into the storyboard one-by-one yourself. But you can carry on using XIBs just fine - there's absolutely no reason you *have* to have a Storyboard, unless there's some specific reason you need it. I generally don't use them very much, even in iOS 7-only apps.